# Identifying similar numbers in 2 strings

Tags: java

I am trying to identify the similar numbers of two telephone numbers.

The similar numbers of these two telephone numbers are 1 3 4 5 6.

```
class yolo1{
     public static void main (String args[]){
           String telUDM="5143436111", telJean="4501234567";
           Integer i=0;
           for(i=0;i<telUDM.length();i++){
               for (j=0;j<telJean.length();j++){
                 if(telUDM.indexOf(i)== telJean.indexOf(j)){
                    System.out.println()/*I am stuck here and do not know what to do from here*/
}}}
```

Comment: What's your definition for "similar numbers"?

Comment: And how could your loop possibly emit `5`?

Comment: i basically want the program to show the same numbers that pops up in the two telephone numbers. I also cant figure out why it emits 5. I am assuming that 5 is in both of the telephone numbers and that the number 5 happens to be the first in telUDM. Im probably wrong but i cant figure out how to display the identical numbers.

Comment: basically you are comparing `telUDM` and `telJean` index by index.  Like is the first char of `telUDM` equals to the first char of `telJean`, then is the second char of `telUDM` equals to the second char of `telJean`.  You need a loop within a loop.

Comment: It's emitting `5` because telUDM[5] == telJean[5] - they're both 3. You're printing the index counted by the for loop, not the number in the position of either phone number.

Comment: try using [String#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: I tried adding another for loop under the one i had already and switched the charAt to indexOf and this time it loops me from 0-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this...**

```
    for (int x=0; x<telUDM.length(); x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<telJean.length(); y++)
        {
                if (telUDM.charAt(x) == telJean.charAt(y))
                      System.out.print(telUDM.charAt(x) + " "); //See comments below                
        }                           
    }
```

Since that if the numbers are the same, just print either one will do.

Comment: is there a reason as to why the numbers are repeating themselves?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using sets:

```
String telUDM  = "5143436111";
String telJean = "4501234567";

Set<Character> tel1 = new HashSet<Character>();
for (char c : telUDM.toCharArray())
    tel1.add(c);

Set<Character> tel2 = new HashSet<Character>();
for (char c : telJean.toCharArray())
    tel2.add(c);

tel1.retainAll(tel2);
List<Character> answer = new ArrayList<Character>(tel1);
Collections.sort(answer);

System.out.println(answer);
=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I haven't learned  how to use arrays in java at the moment. i am trying to solve this problem with the use of loops,charAt and indexOf. ill be keeping this for future reference. Thx

Comment: @user3437460 yet it's more efficient than yours. And if I remove the sorting (that was just for pretty printing) it happens to be an `O(n)` solution, because it's using sets - whereas your solution is `O(n^2)`, thanks to the two nested loops. It's not nice to downvote other people's answers based on a purely subjective opinion - it might seem convoluted, but it's _correct_ and optimal for the problem at hand

Comment: @ÓscarLópez How much faster in terms of run time will it be in this case even if the phone numbers were 100 digits long when you used a O(n) solution compared to a O(n^2) solution. Nothing personal here, this is a common question beginners ask and they don't expect answers like sets, it appears complicated to them.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to the problem is a bit flawed; you're using a looped index utilizing .charAt(). If I used your approach on:

12356
73925

it checks 1 and 7, 2 and 3, 3 and 9, 5 and 2, 6 and 5. It should be checking 1 and 73295, 2 and 73925, etc.

Since your approach makes it seem like you want to use loops, I'd recommend a loop in a loop, like so:

```
`for(i=0;i<telUDM.length();i++){
 for(y = 0; y < telJean.length(); y++) {
 // I'll leave the solution to you.
 //use an Array int[] myArray to add the numbers you want to print
      System.out.println(myArray);`
```

}
}